# What happens to velocity if mass changes, in uniform velocity motion of a body?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, conservation-laws

If a body is in motion with some constant velocity, but its mass is decreasing as it is moving forward, what will happen to its velocity?
Does it stay constant, why?

Comment: You assume at the beginning of your sentence that velocity is constant, so it'll stay constant. If you want to discuss a situation where velocity doesn't remain constant, than you have the specific which forces applies to the system, and/or the law describing the decrease of mass over time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is insufficient information. How exactly is the mass decreasing? In particular, the energy and momentum of the removed mass should be specified

Answer (score 2):

Newtonian mechanics isn't consistent if mass isn't conserved. In a frame of reference where your particle is initially moving, conservation of momentum would require that its velocity change when its mass changes. But in a frame of reference where that same particle is initially at rest, this will result in nonconservation of momentum.

Answer (score 1):

The velocity will increase, so that momentum $\vec p = m \vec v$ is conserved.

The force is defined as
\begin{equation}
\vec F= \frac{d  \vec p}{d t}
\end{equation}

But if there are no external forces on the system ($\vec F=0$), then
\begin{equation}
0= \vec v \frac{ d  m}{d t} + m\frac{d  \vec v }{d t}
\end{equation}

Since the mass is decreasing $dm/dt<0$, a positive acceleration occurs on the body $\vec a= d\vec v/dt>0$, to conserve $\vec p$.

Comment: You assume that conservation of momentum will apply to a system in which mass is _not_ conserved. What is your basis for that assumption?

Comment: @SolomonSlow Hi! In the case where there are no external forces on the system, momentum should be conserved, correct? Given the question is not very elaborated, I answered based on the simple exercise of early undergrad courses where a rocket in space detaches its parts, losing mass and gaining velocity. Are there cases where momentum would not be conserved?

Comment: If a space ship is coasting with its engine off (no force acting on the ship) and it detaches a part without exerting any force between the part and the rest of the ship, then the ship and the part will continue coasting side-by-side with the same velocity as before. The momentum of the "ship" actually is the sum of the momenta of all of its parts. That sum is what gets conserved. You can't decree that the AE-35 unit no longer is part of the ship, but insist that its momentum still belongs to the ship without applying force to transfer that momentum.

Comment: When a rocket accelerates, it loses mass (engine exhaust), and it gains velocity, but there is enormous force between the escaping exhaust and the nozzle and bell of the rocket engine.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation. The other answer also clarifies this point.